# What is exact work of Penatho PDI tool?

Tags: pentaho, etl

I am already using `qlikview` BI tool, it is taking data from its own file as `qvd` for transformed data of original data. So we can get data from `qvd` without hitting db everytime.

Does `pentaho` data integration tool do the same?

Comment: These are questions you should be asking the vendor, or reading the documentation. There is no development question here.

Comment: I agree with @Pogrindis

Answer (score 1):

First thing Pentaho is a big tool, it supports Business Analytic, Data Integration and Reporting. It looks like you are more interested in its ETL capabilities and its comparison with QV so I will answer in that perspective.

QlikView and Pentaho are different. The QVD you are talking about is the direct source for QV dashboard however the QVD needs to be created from some source of data right? That source can be a flat file or database. If your data doesn't change you use the same QVD (which is not the common case) but for any data update you still need to create the QVD again.

On the other hand Pentaho data integration tool is ETL tool. It allows you to do the data transformation (it can be aggregation, Normalization etc. Please read about ETL if you want to understand the capabilities of PDI [Link](http://www.pentaho.com/product/data-integration), [Link2](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Pentaho+Data+Integration+(Kettle)+Tutorial)) and create final data source for you QV reports or any other purpose.

I have used both the tools but not extensively, so if someone feel the answer is incomplete please feel free to add in the answer.